# Crystal Reports 10

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 10.  In the report I have two prompts.

How can I give this report to users such that they can enter the parameters on the web?

Thx in advance,
S.Gyazuddin

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the stand alone crystal reports designer you will need to deploy the report to a web reporting tool such as Crystal Reports Server or Crystal Enterprise.  Then allow your users to access it from there.

If you are using .Net then create an ASP.NET page and add a CrystalReportSource control to your report to the page.  Then add a CrystalReportViewer control to the page that uses your report source and be sure the checkbox for Enable Report Parameter Prompting is checked.  When they load the page it should prompt the user for the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to get you started 
    ReportDocument rpt;

```
//set the datasource 
rpt.SetDataSource(reportDataSet.Tables[0]);

ArrayList reportParameters;  // you filled this arraylist with your values coming from aspx page

//set the parameters for mail report
for (int param = 0; param < reportParameters.Count; param++)
{
    rpt.SetParameterValue(param, reportParameters[param]);
}
```